# How to change treeNode background image

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to use a different background image rather than the default for specific  treeNode.

```
<h:panelGroup id="tree-panel">
        <p:tree 
            id ="tree"
            value="#{processBean.root}" 
            var="sp" 
            dynamic="false" 
            cache="true" 
            animate="true"
            selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{processBean.selectedNode}"
            rendered="#{processBean.renderTree}"> 
            <p:treeNode type="csp" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed"
                        expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open"
                        styleClass="jdhf">  
                <h:outputText value="#{sp}" />  
            </p:treeNode>
            <p:treeNode type="ncsp" icon="ui-icon-document" >  
                <h:outputText value="#{sp}" />  
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree> 
    </h:panelGroup>


.jdhf {
background-image: url("#{resource['primefaces-redmond/images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png']}");
}
```

How can I change the style for the first node (csp)?

Thanks

Comment: With css.. Just make sure you selector is more specific than the default one

Comment: can you please add some example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
 <p:treeNode type="ncsp" icon="ui-icon-document" styleClass="custom">  
                <h:outputText value="#{sp}" />  
            </p:treeNode>


.custom .ui-treenode-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("#{resource['primefaces-redmond/images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png']}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where your selector is not specific enough. An example of specificity can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (including a clear explanation).

In this specific case, putting `#tree` in front of `.jdhf` in your css selector will solve it

So

```
#tree .jdhf {…}
```